# How to move if else statement in validation() method from doGet() method

Tags: java, refactoring

This is my code. I need help for moving all if else in another method called `validation()` so I can optimize it and not use the same code over and over again. What should I do? Can I make this new method inside `doGet()` method or I have to place it over/under it?

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Currency() {
    super();
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String currencyCode = request.getParameter("currencyCode");
    String currencyValue = request.getParameter("currencyValue");

    double result = 0;

    if (currencyCode.equals("") && currencyValue.equals("")) {
        // end user display
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<head>");
        out.print("<title>Value Convertor</title>");
        out.print("</head>");
        out.print("<body><br>");
        out.print("<h1>ERROR! Code and Value are not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.</h1>");
        out.print("</body>");
        out.print("<html>");
        System.out.println(
                "ERROR! currencyCode and currencyValue are not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.");
    } else if (currencyCode.equals("")) {
        // end user display
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<head>");
        out.print("<title>Value Convertor</title>");
        out.print("</head>");
        out.print("<body><br>");
        out.print("<h1>ERROR! Code is not set. Please enter Code you want to exchange.</h1>");
        out.print("</body>");
        out.print("<html>");
        System.out.println("ERROR! currencyCode is not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.");
    } else if (currencyValue.equals("")) {
        // end user display
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<head>");
        out.print("<title>Value Convertor</title>");
        out.print("</head>");
        out.print("<body><br>");
        out.print("<h1>ERROR! Value is not set. Please enter Value se we can exchange your currency.</h1>");
        out.print("</body>");
        out.print("<html>");
        System.out.println("ERROR! currencyValue is not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.");
    }

    // DB
    Connection conn = null;

    double exchange = 1;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        // String URL = ;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/currency", "postgres", "amdcs16");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st
                .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM currency_exchange WHERE currency_code = '" + currencyCode + "'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Displaying data of tables
            System.out.println("Your currency is: " + rs.getString("currency_code"));
            System.out.println("The rate of currency is: " + rs.getString("exchange"));
            exchange = rs.getDouble("exchange");
            System.out.println("Exchange: " + exchange);
        }
        st.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    double currValue = Double.parseDouble(currencyValue);
    result = exchange * currValue;
    // end user display
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html>");
    out.print("<head>");
    out.print("<title>Value Convertor</title>");
    out.print("</head>");
    out.print("<body><br>");
    out.print("<h1>The exchange (BGN/" + currencyCode + ") is " + result + "</h1>");
    out.print("</body>");
    out.print("<html>");
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Can you give me some advise or any example that can help me? I will appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Create a method `private void validate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`  over or under the `doGet` (doesn't matter), and put all the if-else statements inside. Furthermore `currencyValue.isEmpty()` is equivalent to `currencyValue.equals("")`

Comment: You can move you <html> tags in one method, its repeating always, so just add variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract a method:

```
private void printOutput(HttpServletResponse response, String msg3) {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html>");
    out.print("<head>");
    out.print("<title>Value Convertor</title>");
    out.print("</head>");
    out.print("<body><br>");
    out.print("<h1>" + msg + "</h1>");
    out.print("</body>");
    out.print("<html>");
}

if (currencyCode.equals("") && currencyValue.equals("")) {
    printOutput(response, "ERROR! Code and Value are not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.");
    System.out.println(
            "ERROR! currencyCode and currencyValue are not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.");
} else if (currencyCode.equals("")) {
    printOutput(response, "ERROR! Code is not set. Please enter Code you want to exchange.</h1>");
    System.out.println("ERROR! currencyCode is not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.");
} else if (currencyValue.equals("")) {
    printOutput(response, "ERROR! Value is not set. Please enter Value se we can exchange your currency.</h1>");
    System.out.println("ERROR! currencyValue is not set. Please enter Code and Value you want to exchange.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i appreciate it. Can you just tell me where should i place it, inside or outside `doGet()` method? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: It will be fine, at outside, you just have to call these methods

Comment: @VakacTodorov You can include the helper method in the same class as where `doGet()` appears.